# Content Security Policy reports WSS violation, but no code calls this protocol

Tags: .net, url-scheme, content-security-policy

We have recently implemented Content Security Policy in one of our .NET web apps.  So far, it has been working just fine and the errors reported all make sense.  However, there is one `connect-src` error that pops up that we cannot identify:

> WSS://my.website.com

The `Document URI` is a valid page and uses `HTTPS`.  The `Source File` is blank. The site is only `HTTPS` and if the client tries to use `HTTP`, they are redirected to `HTTPS`.  So where is this `WSS` protocol coming from?  As far as I know, we have no code that uses this protocol.  Is there something in the .NET stack that uses it under the covers?
It happens on different pages seemingly a random.  Has anyone experienced this or can someone tell me what it is doing?

I know I can add this WSS to the directive, but I'd rather know what it is and why it is happening before I start making allowances for it.

Comment: Hi, Justin. I have found the same problem on our sites. Did you resolve your problem? Can you share your solution?

Comment: Nothing yet.  Best we can do so afar is ignore this particular violation.

Comment: I just ran into this because I'm using SignalR, which uses wss://. The solution was just to add wss://my.website.com to the connect-src.


One note: if you use this with dev/staging, you'll have to include those URL's in your connect-src as well, or generate them at runtime referring only to the servers in that environment. I have a CSP middleware that does exactly that so I don't leak my dev/staging environment servers in production.